# mongodb map emit keys from subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a document which includes a subdocument:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXX"),
    "SearchKey" : "1234",
    "SearchTerms" : {
        "STA" : ["1"],
        "STB" : ["asdfasdf"],
        "STC" : ["another"]
    }
}
```

The SearchTerm elements are not fixed - sometimes we'll have STA without STC, for example.

I can do this:

```
var map = function() {
    for (key in this.SearchTerms)
    {
        emit(key, 1);
    }
}
```

but I can't do this:

```
var map = function() {
    for (var i=0; i< this.SearchTerms.length; i++)
    {
        emit(this.SearchTerms[i], 1)
    }
}
```

because the latter doesn't produce any results after the reduce.  Why not?

As an aside - what I need to do is count the cross-product of the search terms over all documents, that is, find the incidence of (STA and STB) and (STA and STC) and (STB and STC) in the case above.  If someone knows how to do that right away, that works even better.

As always, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key that you emit should be a composite of both keys.

```
    var map = function() {
        if(!this.SearchTerms) return;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < this.SearchTerms.length; i++){
            var outerKey = this.SearchTerms[i];
            for(var j = i + 1; j < this.SearchTerms.length; j++){
               var innerKey = this.SearchTerms[j];
               // assuming you don't care about counting (STA and STC) separately from (STC and STA), 
               // then order doesn't matter, lets make sure both occurences have the same key.
               var compositeKey = (outerKey < innerKey) ? outerKey+"_"+innerKey : innerKey+"_"+outerKey; 
               emit(compositeKey, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The general idea is great - but won't the above count all combinations twice?  Once for outerkey < innerkey and once for innerkey > outerkey?

Comment: you're storing every pair twice, that's totally unnecessary, just wasting disk and CPU.

Comment: how so? notice the inner loop starts at `i+1`? Can you provide a better answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `this.SearchTerms` is a dictionary/subdocument and not an array. `this.SearchTerms[0]` doesn't exist.

For the second question: something like this should work:

```
for (key1 in this.SearchTerms)
{
  for (key2 in this.SearchTerms)
  {       
    if (key1 < key2)
    {
      key = [key1, key2];
      emit(key, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error: "_id cannot be an array", but if I do something like key=key1 + "_" + key2 it works.  Thanks a million!